# Why an instance can not be serialized with JSON?

Tags: python, json, serialization, deserialization

As I'm trying to solve "Not JSON serializable" problems for the last couple of hours, I'm very interested in what the hard part is while serializing and deserializing an instance.

Why a class instance can not be serialized - for example - with JSON?

To serialize:

1. Note the class name (in order to rebuild the object)
2. Note the variable values at the time of packaging.
3. Convert it to string.
4. Optionally compress it (as msgpack does)

To deserialize:

1. Create a new instance
2. Assign known values to appropriate variables
3. Return the object.

What is difficult? What is complex data type?

Comment: Why do you want to serialize an instance with json? why not pickle?

Comment: I'm using RabbitMQ+pickle, I have no problem with pickle. Now I try to use ZeroRPC, which uses msgpack, which complains about one of my classes (I don't know exactly what causes that error). Msgpack says "It packs everything that Json packs". Json does not pack my instance. Ok. I give up. But I'm very very interested in what is so hard to achieve while one another serializer could make.

Answer (score 0):

The "hard" part is mainly step 3 of your serialization, converting the contained values to strings (and later back during deserialization)

For simple types like numbers, strings, booleans, it's quite straight forward, but for complex types like a socket connected to a remote server or an open file descriptor, it won't work very well.

The solution is usually to either move the complex types from the types you want to serialize and keep the serialized types very clean, or somehow tag or otherwise tell the serializers exactly which properties should be serialized, and which should not.

Comment: Ok. What makes an open file descriptor or a socket complex? Can not they be defined by standard data types (int, string...)? What makes them so complicated?

Comment: @ceremcem An open file would imply that you could read 100 bytes, serialize the object with the open file descriptor and ship it to another computer. When the other computer deserializes the object and calls read to read the next 100 bytes, the file may not even exist there. Same thing with a socket; if you open a connection to google and send it a search, serialize the socket and deserialize it weeks later on another computer, how would you resume the connection so that you could get the answer that was sent on the original socket?

Comment: @ceremcem Basically, objects with state that is not entirely contained in the object itself (such as the OS or the network) are at least not straight forward to serialize, so the serializer - to keep it easy - usually just gives up.

Comment: Can't we just pass the data and let google or our class handle the rest? Maybe google will respond even in the next year, or our class will try to reconnect?

Comment: Sorry for reinvent the wheel: I'm talking about exactly what jsonpickle does.